# XSD to Delphi Classes without XML binding

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd, code-generation

Perhaps this has been asked before, but I haven't found it with regards to Delphi - I have used a XSD.exe in Visual Studio that does exactly this: converts XSD into ***'plain vanilla'*** classes representing the entities specified in the XSD - not bound to XML document - classes for creating the structures in the XSD, not accessing data that conforms to the structure outlined in the XSD.

I am looking for a utility or product that will do this (that doesn't cost big bucks...) : Example, I have a schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="TDelphiClass">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ID"/>
                <xs:element ref="ConnectionString"/>
                <xs:element ref="Group"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="ConnectionString" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Group"type="xs:double"/>
</xs:schema>
```

I want to generate a Delphi unit/class that looks like this:

```
unit uDelphiClass;

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

type
  TDelphiClass = class(TObject)
    fID: Integer;
    fConnectionString: string;
    fGroup: Double;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When editing your posts, please don't remove the code formatting. Read the FAQ (visible during editing) about code formatting: it helps everyone keeping a clear picture of what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading between the lines (please use less abbreviations, for instance, [VS has multiple meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VS), even in computing), and You probably used the [XSD.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) tool in Visual Studio or the .NET SDK to generate your source code in the C# or VB.NET language.

If you have [Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism), you can [use XSD.EXE to generate Delphi Prism source code](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/net-delphi-prism-how-to-generate-wrapper-classes-code-from-xsd-file/).

The Delphi Prism language is very close to the Delphi native language, so that will give you a kick start.

This should work with the Delphi Prism trial too.

BTW: Why do you not want to use the Delphi native code generated by the [XML Data Binding Wizard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D78MG4CaAI) in a standalone way? It is interface based, but is pretty fast and works very well.

Comment: sorry about the formatting etc - I generally don't get on to SO until VERY LATE at night... and yes, it was XSD.exe with a couple of parameters to get that result. As for the delphi data binding wizard, if it was a schema like my example, it wouldn't be a problem - but with a large complex schema it takes a good deal of work to refit things - particularly because the databinding wizard assumes you're persisting data with an xml doc and when you want 'plain vanilla' delphi classes you need to set up fields and property getters/setters for that. Will investigate the Prism tool. Tnx-MNG

Comment: @Mikey: note that large complex schema's usually cannot mapped to 'normal' programming languages in an automated way.

Comment: I had greate success with the MS tool, even on fairly complex schemas with nested classes, enumerations, numerous restrictions, etc. The trick is to know how to write the **RIGHT** XSD (no, not all that easy...) so that the generator does what you want.

Comment: @Mikey: indeed! Too bad I usually get external XSD to work with :)

Comment: let's hope JSON continues to G_R_O_W... so much nicer!

Answer (score 4):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xxsd2code/ generates C++, C#, C++/CLI and Java - and it looks like the included 'LanguageWriter' classes are not too complicated to extend them for Delphi. The [Java LanguageWriter](http://xxsd2code.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xxsd2code/trunk/XXsd2Code/LanguageWriters/JavaWriter.cs?revision=14&view=markup) for example has less than 400 lines. If there is interest in the Delphi community this could be implemented and contributed in a short timeframe...

Comment: I will check it out. But I wonder why there has never been much interest in this. I write mostly middleware and server side code that often has to interface with Java and C# clients - the best way to ensure that everyone will be able to talk to you is to define your classes from the outset using XSD.