# How can I get something like delphi data binding wizard for use with Delphi 7?

Tags: xml, delphi, class, xsd, delphi-7

I need to generate a Delphi 7 class from an xsd file so we can import strongly typed xml data into Delphi 7 Pro.  We have one xml file and the xsd file.

We only have Delphi 7 Pro. I heard the the Data Binding Wizard (available in D7 Enterprise) can create this “xml class” via the XSD so we can import the Xml into a strongly typed Delphi 7 class object.  What is the most cost effective way for us to get the Data binding Wizard? or is there another way? We do not need the other functionality of D7 Enterprise.

We also have a DLL of a c# class based on the xsd (xsd.exe) we could have used if we were using C#...  Can Delphi 7 easily use a .NET DLL to import XML or not?  The Microsoft xsd.exe tool lets you generate the class for free.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSD to Delphi Classes without XML binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853820/xsd-to-delphi-classes-without-xml-binding)

Comment: Does Delphi 7 Pro have the WSDL importer (see main menu > New > Other, is there a WebServices tab with the WSDL importer?)
If so you could in theory convert the xsd into a wsdl and use this to generate a Delphi wrapper.

Comment: *TIP: get a higher delphi version (trial...), and use the code generated by the wizard in D7?

Answer (score 0):

Delphi can interact and work with .NET packages through the [Delphi .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphinet/) package.  I have used this in the past, and even though it's not actively maintained, it is stable and works pretty well for communication between Delphi and .NET.

I don't know about a data binding wizard though, as I only have the professional version available to me, though I have seen components available on Torry's site for parsing XML that can be used directly in Delphi.

Comment: The data binding wizard isn't for parsing XML; Delphi has supported MSXML (and other DOM vendors) through TXMLDocument since MSXML was originally released (Delphi 3?). The data binding wizard is an IDE dialog that uses your XML or XSD flies to auto-generate Delphi class wrappers that allow type-safe use of XML. As far as the Delphi.NET package, it's not needed if the .NET classes export a typelibrary, as Delphi can import it natively.

Comment: @Ken White That's fine.  I had to use the Delphi .NET stuff for a project when I was working with Delphi 5 as the .NET code we had didn't export a type library Delphi could read.  Also, I don't remember ever seeing the TXMLDocument in Delphi 5, but my memory could be going.